# Is the MD5 checksum for 18.04.1 image available?

Tags: checksums

Last night I downloaded via torrents the disk image `ubuntu-18.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso` . Downloading via the official website was taking too long and but using torrents allowed me to download the image pretty quickly. I was also able to install the OS, and it seems to be working so far pppretty smoothly.

However, just to be safe, I would like to verify if the .iso that I have downloaded is correct and not been tampered with.

I tried searching for the md5sums of the 18.04.1 image, but I couldn't find it on http://releases.ubuntu.com/ or elsewhere. The checksum for 18.04.4 is available but I can't seem to find the  .1 version.

Can someone point me to the checksum files for this particular iso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obsolete point releases are archived in http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/.

Specifically, you're looking for http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/18.04.1/MD5SUMS:

```
f430da8fa59d2f5f4262518e3c177246 *ubuntu-18.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso
188741f61c23d112a2564b0a864e25a3 *ubuntu-18.04.1-live-server-amd64.iso
c792bb06807658543fa504b84f90ba41 *ubuntu-18.04.1-preinstalled-server-armhf+raspi2.img.xz
e8264fa4c417216f4304079bd94f895e *ubuntu-18.04.1-server-amd64.iso
8d6978164a38c401b373a3eb32ef0c67 *ubuntu-18.04.1-server-arm64.iso
8f4b57602abb21a5070cfbf5756048e4 *ubuntu-18.04.1-server-ppc64el.iso
350f62d3d8fbeb7c8418bbc22362d0ab *ubuntu-18.04.1-server-s390x.iso
188741f61c23d112a2564b0a864e25a3 *ubuntu-18.04.1.0-live-server-amd64.iso
```

That's also probably why the download was slow. The old-releases repository isn't intended for heavy usage.

Comment: Wonderful! I verified my image and indeed, one of the md5sums you listed turned out to be the md5sum of the image I downloaded. Thanks!